# WordPress additonal check while login

Tags: wordpress

When a user register in my site I have set the `user_activation_key` column value from `wp_users` table like that:

```
$code = sha1( $user_id . time() );   

global $wpdb; 

$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->prefix.'users', //table name     
    array( 'user_activation_key' => $code ),       
    array( 'ID' =>    $user_id ),     
    array( '%s' ),
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

It's because I want to make activation system by sending an email with clickable link:

```
$activation_link = add_query_arg( 
    array( 
        'key' => $code, 
        'user' => $user_id 
    ), get_permalink( 44 )
);  

$message = "<div style='padding : 20px; border : 1px solid #ddd; color : #000;'>Hello $surname, <br/><br/>Please confirm your email addresss . Click this link to confirm : <a href='$activation_link'>Confirm Now</a><br/><br/></div>";

$to         = $email;
$subject    = 'Confirm your registration process"';
$body       = $message;
$headers    = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Now, the column `user_activation_key` has the hash code and `user_status` column value is 0

**Now the actual question:**

When user go to www.site.com/wp-admin that means login page I want to show an error message if the `user_status` column value is 0.

**I don't' have any idea which hook or how can I cehck this while user login?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the admin_notices hook to display messages in the backend, the code below is similar to what your after:

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'account_activation_check');

function account_activation_check() {
  global $wpdb;
  // setup vars //
  $currentID = get_current_user_id();
  $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $currentID );
  $userStatus = $user->user_status;
  // check if user status is 0 //
  if($userStatus == 0) {
    echo '<div class="error"><p>Your email has not been verified!</p></div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issues by using the `wp_authenticate_user` hook. Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'shibbir_authenticate_user', 10, 2 );
function shibbir_authenticate_user( $user ) {
    if ( $user->data->user_status  == 0 ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', __( 'Your account is not activate, Please contact site admininstrator.' , 'shibbir' ) );
    }
    return $user;
}
```